# VB 2013 Application Out of Memory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, out-of-memory, backgroundworker

I'm new to VB but recently created my first working app :) Anyway it just compresses files and little bit more. The latest thing that I added was a marquee style progress bar to animate while the operation was in progress and stop when it ends and the user can do the next zip operation. The progress bar wasn't updating, so I used a background worker to do the actual task while the button click just did the animation. Since then I've notcied serious degredation in the app. It struggles to load. I even got an out of memory error. Not sure if the background worker is related, but I thought I'd mention as it was the last update. Has anyone experienced anything similar? If I can provide and specific info, please ask me for it! Many thanks.

UPDATE: So I understand that I'm not using the BGWorker correctly. I will change that. But I found even with that removed, I still had issues. So I created a new form and started adding in bits of my code one by one. Anyway, I fell at the first hurdle with my form load sub. So I added that in slowly. I found that when ever I have any statements that load a variable from settings for persistent settings that the app falls over. Below is my code. Can anyone see what's up?????

UPDATE: I've found that if I load from settings the memory useage shoots up. I tried this too with saving settins on form closed. Below is the error received. The same out of memory occurs when trying to load settings too. I never experienced this on the first form I created. So perhaps I have missed some settings on the second, because the implementation in the code hasn't changed.

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to save settings: An error occurred executing the configuration section handler for userSettings/Backup_Tool.My.MySettings. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred executing the configuration section handler for userSettings/Backup_Tool.My.MySettings. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

This is when I added in the code below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed

    ' TAB PAGE 1.

    ' Save controls to settings.

    My.Settings.StartPathTextBox1 = StartPathTextBox1.Text
    My.Settings.ZipPathTextBox1 = ZipPathTextBox1.Text
    My.Settings.CopyPathTextBox1 = CopyPathTextBox1.Text

    My.Settings.ZipSelectCheckBox1 = ZipSelectCheckBox1.Checked
    My.Settings.CopySelectCheckBox1 = CopySelectCheckBox1.Checked

    For Each s As String In StartNameListBox1.Items()
        My.Settings.StartNameListBoxItems1.Add(s)
    Next

    For Each s As String In StartNameListBox1.SelectedItems()
        My.Settings.StartNameListBoxSelectedItems1.Add(s)
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' FORM 1.

    ' Initialise specialised string collections.

    If My.Settings.StartNameListBoxItems1 Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.StartNameListBoxItems1 = _
            New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
    End If

    If My.Settings.StartNameListBoxSelectedItems1 Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.StartNameListBoxSelectedItems1 = _
            New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
    End If

    ' TAB PAGE 1.

    ' Restore controls from saved settings.

    StartPathTextBox1.Text() = My.Settings.StartPathTextBox1
    ZipPathTextBox1.Text() = My.Settings.ZipPathTextBox1
    CopyPathTextBox1.Text() = My.Settings.CopyPathTextBox1

    ZipSelectCheckBox1.Checked = My.Settings.ZipSelectCheckBox1
    CopySelectCheckBox1.Checked = My.Settings.CopySelectCheckBox1

    For Each s As String In My.Settings.StartNameListBoxItems1()
        StartNameListBox1.Items.Add(s)
    Next

    For Each s As String In My.Settings.StartNameListBoxSelectedItems1()
        StartNameListBox1.SelectedItems.Add(s)
    Next

    ' Decide controls initial states.

    If StartNameListBox1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        ZipSelectCheckBox1.Enabled = False
        RunButton1.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ZipSelectCheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        ZipPathTextBox1.Enabled = False
        ZipBrowseButton1.Enabled = False
    End If

    If ZipPathTextBox1.Text = String.Empty Then
        CopySelectCheckBox1.Enabled = False
    End If

    If CopySelectCheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        CopyPathTextBox1.Enabled = False
        CopyBrowseButton1.Enabled = False
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Sure, post your code and I can almost bet your not using the background worker correctly...

Comment: I'm just reading about not to access controls from within the "do work" event, which I am doing. So I will try and adapt my code now and post my progress.

Comment: please post your code in your question with format, it's hard to understand your code

Comment: Hi, apologies I will edit my question rather than comments in future. That being said, the code I posted doesn't really matter now. I know the problem is because I was trying to access controls on my form directly from the background worker, which is not allowed. I need a way to pass the text and selected items from three textboxes and a listbox to the background worker. I don't need to retrieve. If you've done this before then please explain how, otherwise I will continue reading and hopefully post my attempts soon! Thanks for responding!

Comment: One more comment. I removed the backgroundworker altogether as an initial test before I get a solution, and the same problem exists? I'm going to correct my code anyway to use the background worker properly, but perhaps I should introduce on a new form!

Comment: Programming requires precision. No one here is going to know what "my code falls over" means.  Does it throw an error?  Where?  What is the error message?  Help us help you.  If you have code in some of those control's events like CheckChanged.  That code will execute when you set the CheckState from code which might be the source of "falling over" depending on what they are doing.

Comment: @Plutonix - I added the error into the above comment. This occurred when I tried to save to settings on form close. I see in task manager/properties the memory useage shoot up. App is slow to close sometimes resulting in that error. This is the same case for if I add code from above back into to load settings on form load. If I remove all instances of loading from/saving to settings than the app start and closes absolutley fine.

Comment: it appears that you are only adding to `My.Settings.StartNameListBoxItems1` and the other each time you exit; which means they would be accumulating lots of duplicates. this should result in the form listboxes being very long and containing dupes or old items - scroll the list and see.  In form close, add a `.Clear` for each settings collection to remove all the previous items before adding the current ones.

Comment: @Plutonix - Each time the user uses the folder browse dialog and selects OK, I do "items.clear()" as to not add to the list box and so the listbox is only representitive of the contents of the folder they browsed too. Of course I've not posted this code so you wouldn't have known. Do you still see an issue or my answer clears that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *appears* to be that you are only ever adding the current selections to the Settings collections.  You might well clear the `ListBox` when they make new selections, but you do not do the same thing with the Settings Collections like `My.Settings.StartNameListBoxItems1`:

```
For Each s As String In StartNameListBox1.Items()
    My.Settings.StartNameListBoxItems1.Add(s)
Next
```

The collection will have all the items in it from all the other times it has ever run already and you are now going to add more to it.  Eventually you will have many, many, many items in it.

```
My.Settings.StartNameListBoxItems1.Clear   ' REMOVE ALL OLD ITEMS
' Save just the current items to the collection
For Each s As String In StartNameListBox1.Items()
    My.Settings.StartNameListBoxItems1.Add(s)
Next
```

use .Clear on both Collections

Comment: You're a hundred percent correct. Seems an obvious one to miss now :( Many thanks!!!

Comment: based on your other question it sounds like you might be better off loading Settings collections to something else like a List<T> instead of directly to the ListBox so that a BGW can process the items as a ToTo list.

Comment: One other thought, if I each time the user changed the selected index of the list box, if i changed to clearing the old selected items and adding the new at that point (rather than at form close) so it was always up to date, In the BGW could I just loop through the my.settings in the saem way that I do to add to the list box? Or is there reason's for and against? Otherwise I will attempt at what you said. Just a thought I had.

Comment: This works anyway. But if you have any for or againsts doing this in terms of best practice let me know. If there's no problem I could do this for all the info I need in the BGW which is only three paths in three textboxes, so not much.

Comment: I would use Settings only for what it was intended for and create my own variable for my own use.  Presumably in the BGW task you might do something with the list like set a Processed flag or something.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to look into this now. Thanks for the insight. YOu've been extremely helpful throughout!