# VB 2013 Passing Listbox Selected Items to a Background Worker

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, arguments, backgroundworker

I need to pass data from form controls to a background worker. I've done this with textboxes and a single selected item of a listbox. Please see below:

```
Public Class BackgroundWorkerArguments

    Public StartName1 As String

End Class

Private Sub RunButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RunButton1.Click

    Dim Arguments As BackgroundWorkerArguments = New BackgroundWorkerArguments()

        Arguments.StartName1 = StartNameListBox.SelectedItem

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

Dim Arguments As BackgroundWorkerArguments = CType(e.Argument, BackgroundWorkerArguments)

Dim StartName As String = Arguments.StartName1 

End Sub
```

I'd like to implement this in a loop to add all of the listbox selected items. I tried this in the button click:

```
For Each s As String In StartNameListBox1.SelectedItems()

        Arguments.StartName1 = s

    Next
```

And to recover in the background worker I tried:

```
Dim Arguments As BackgroundWorkerArguments = CType(e.Argument, BackgroundWorkerArguments)

    For Each s As String In Arguments.StartName1

        Dim StartName As String = s

    Next
```

However it only returns a single character. Anyway I have a loop that for each folder name in the list box that is selected it zips up those folders. When I run the program the zip that appears is empty and only has a single character at most. If I use the first method with just one selected item everything works fine. SO I can't be too far away! If anyone can point me in the rigth direction than please let me know. Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
' Fills path of browsed folder into first text box.

    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        StartPathTextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
        StartNameListBox1.Items.Clear()

        ' Fills foldernames within browsed folder into listbox.

        For Each s As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(StartPathTextBox1.Text)
            StartNameListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(s))
        Next
```

Comment: BGWs are usually used to perform tasks that will take a while, not process UI elements.  If you used a `List(of String)` or `List(of myClass)` (or BindingList<T>) for the items and used them as the DataSource for the ListBox(es), the BGW could process the list to do whatever.  If things change in the list, the ProgressChanged event could update the UI controls.  The way it looks, you are using a BGW to act on one thing (StartName1 which is just one item).

Comment: @Plutonix - Hi again. What happens in the program is once a user browses to a folder the listbox populates with folder names. I use that list to use the zip class to zip up every item selected. So that list I use to gather the folder names when describing paths to the folders to be zipped and where to zip them to. Can I use the selected items to generate another list that the BGW can then read?

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx): `You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.` Besides which, you do not want the user to CHANGE their selections in the UI while it is being processed.  Use a variable like a List<T>

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for the extra info. You raised a good point. I've disabled the run button from the user for the duration of the task. Of course I could do the same for the rest of the items but I think at what you're hinting i.e. still giving the user access to the UI but just not affecting anything on-going (rather than what I just suggested doing, disabling everything) is best. This is a much cleaner idea and I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: [Using a List(Of T)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23679571/1070452) to store stuff for a Listbox; [Similar but uses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23205262/1070452) a file based class which might apply to your task

Comment: @Plutonix - Hi Sorry to bother. I know you've but a couple of links there. But I'm still not getting how to add textbox.text and listbox.selected items to a single list for retrieval in the background worker. You don't have to write code but if you can just right a couple of point of the order I should do things, then I can look at each point. Thanks if you can help some more!

Comment: The BGW issue is that it ought not play with UI controls.  If the ToDo list is a collection variable list List(Of String) (or List(of file) see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24397531/1070452 ), then BGW can access it as it needs.  The list can be the datasource for the ListBox so there is no duplicated data.  If BGW works off a `For n` it can report the percentage complete in the loop very easily (n / myList.Count ).  I would leave BGW out of the equation for now and simply implement a List(OF T) to get that part correct first.

Comment: **right from the start** you have a design decision - whether the List(T) is to be a List(of String) or List(of myFileClass).  the latter allows things like displaying "Foobar.jpg" in the listbox while retaining the full pathname as a property for the code to use.  the last link somewhat illustrates this.  I have no idea if it fully applies to what you are doing, I can only go by how I might do it...

Comment: @Plutonix I would like in a button click event for what ever is displayed in the textbox and selected in the listbox to update a list that will then hand off to the BGW that will be called in the click event. This will be the data source for the operation to follow, But I can't workout how to get that into a list? I've put some code above for how I'm currently updating the boxes, do you think it would be easier to add to a list from there?

Comment: that last link is **highly** applicable.  the Fullpath property replaces TextBox and File name replaces the ListBox items; put them in a List (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24397531/1070452 shows how).  the list can be the datasource for the ListBox **and** the ToDo list for the zipping work.  rather than deal with TWO new things (Lists and BGW), skip BGW for now and get it working with a list.  Once the real work (zipping) is not using UI controls for the data, adding in a BGW will be easier.  There are 2 different things with 2 different uses and learning curves, tackle them one at a time.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks again. I'll take your advice and climb some hills! :)

Comment: @Plutonix,  wrong I would say. I use background workers for many processes that deal with the UI. You can manipulate UI controls in the do work with delegates, which is proper. There's nothing wrong and works just fine if your doing it correctly.

Comment: @User3688529 don't ask a question and accept it, then ask the same issue again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB 2013 Application Out of Memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640648/vb-2013-application-out-of-memory)

Comment: delegates == "ways around this"; however these are hardly a novice level technique which the OP clearly is.  Further, detaching the Files List from the UI has numerous other advantages.  What happens if the user changes the listbox SelectedItems WHILE it is being iterated elsewhere, for instance?  Finally, using a BGW is not at all related to his Out of Memory issue other than it is located in the same program.  The first was an oversight dealing with Settings, which are not even mentioned in the present question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN: `You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler.  Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.`  There are ways around this but since the main UI access needed is updating a ProgressBar, the ProgressChanged event will suffice nicely.

There is a bigger problem.  A BGW will leave the UI responsive which means the user could add, change or remove items from the SelectedItems *while you are processing it in the BGW*.  The contents of a collection cant be allowed to change while it is being processed or your code could run out of items or miss items.

Perhaps more importantly, relying on UI controls like TextBoxes and ListBoxes inexorably binds your code logic to that form making it difficult to move and reuse your code in other programs.  Rather than a `ListBox` you can use a List variable to store the list of things to do.  This will use a `List (of String)`

```
Public Class Form1

    ' module/form level variables for our use
    Private allFilesAs List(Of String)
    Private zFolder As String

    ' in form load, create instance
    allFiles = New List(of String)
```

Then the procedure to load the files:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(...etc

    ' clear datasource for when user selects a new folder
    filesLB.DataSource = Nothing

    Using fb As New FolderBrowserDialog
        ' use old name as starting point if set
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(zFolder) Then
            zFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(_
                   Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        End If
        fb.SelectedPath = zFolder 

        If fb.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        zFolder = fb.SelectedPath

        ' display selection, but do not allow text edit           
        labelFolder.Text = zFolder 
    End Using

    zFiles.Clear()         ' clear the list from last time

    ' loop thru files
    For Each s As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(zFolder)

        ' add to list
        allFiles.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(s))
    Next

    ' set datasource of listbox to this list
    ' contents of myFiles will automagically appear
    filesLB.DataSource = allFiles

End Sub
```

The data is actually in our `allFiles` list variable.  Using it as the ListBox.Datasource allows it to display the list there without copying the data.  If your code was to make many changes to the list, you could use a `BindingList(Of T)` and those changes would show in the UI as you update.

> Note that if you were processing files from *different* folders, you would need something like a FileClass to store a folder name with *each* file. A custom FileClass and a `List(Of FileClass)` would allow that flexibility.

Currently, you are chopping the path off then gluing it back on from on from a textbox which the user may have changed to an invalid location.   This saves the folder to a `zFolder` variable and reuses it.

There are several ways to process the list.  `SelectedItems` is a valid collection and could be used as a ToDo list in many cases.  As noted, if you are edging towards using a BackgroundWorker, the user could change that collection while you are processing it, so we copy the items to a new list to prevent that.  I am not using a second UI ListBox because the user can already see what is selected so it is redundant; this list is for our use:

```
zFiles = New List(Of String)

' harvest selected files
For Each o As Object In filesLB.SelectedItems
    ' Selected items contains Object, cast back
    ' to string for the List
    zFiles.Add(Path.Combine(zFolder, CType(o, String))
Next

' ToDo: Zip the files in that zFiles list.
```

The file list to zip are not in the UI but under our control in variable.

---

The *best way* would be to create a `Zipper` class where all your zip related procedures and such are `encapsulated`.  As is, they are likely intermingled with form code and probably all in event procedures.  A `Zipper Class` would detach the core logic from the UI and let you create other Zip related programs much faster by adding your Zip Class to that project.  We like `reusable` code and this is probably more worth the time to learn than a BGW.  In that case, the `zFiles` above could be a collection property:

```
Private Z AS New Zipper

'...
For Each o As Object In filesLB.SelectedItems

    Z.Files.Add(Path.Combine(zFolder, CType(o, String))

Next
Z.Zip          ' method to process indicated files
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the wealth of info. I certainly understand your points about removing the input I'm using from the UI thread. I will take on board all of these comments and will set about improving the structure of my project!

Comment: I'm currently doing one of your first steps in the button click. On first pass the folder browse updates the list and subsequently the listbox. On second pass the listbox remains the same. The only way I have got it to update on each pass is to create a new instance of the list on each folder browse. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I dont understand why there are `passes`.  Is this for when they click a for a new directory?  In that case, binding from *this* list is not dynamic.  At the start of the Click event above add `listboxName.DataSource = Nothing`.  Another way is to use a `BindingList<T>` instead; if you had Remove/Up/Dn actions for the list, I would have suggested it instead.  **If** one of those Settings lists is merely the contents of a LB which in turn is a files list, all you really need to store for it is the selected folder.  You could reload the LB from that (esp since files change)

Comment: Yes that is correct. I want the user to be able to select new directories and the listbox. Removing the data source first as per your suggestion works great. So now I'll do the same and compile a seperate list for the zipping.

Comment: One question. At the moment with the current app using a background worker, I have a couple of useful features like reporting for updating the UI, cancellation for stop after the next zip if I'm running a batch operation. No doubt these can be implemented when making your own classes, but who easy would this be? I ask as until my skill set increases for the current app maybe I'm best sticking with the BGW, although implementing your lists to keep the UI and process apart. What are your thoughts?

Comment: the code running as a BGW can reference *variables* from the main thread normally - it is UI controls which need special handling. (part of the reason for `zFolder` in teh answer was to show how to do simple  code vars that arent UI related).   So with a CANCEL button which simply sets `ZCancel = True`, your current bgw code could look at that and respond. Be sure to reset ZCancel each time though.